# Auto mount active directory users home folder to Ubuntu

Tags: automount

We are working in the Windows environment and need to move to Linux; we joind our Linux PCs to the AD domain with centrfy, which is likewise open, and both are easy. Every user has an home folder in the Windows AD like:

```
\\ourserver\profile\user_name
```

and share folder:

```
\\windowsfileserver\groupname
```

And we block access to the local hard disk and USB drive. Only the home folder and shared folder are accessible. What is the best way to mount the home folder which assigned in the active directory to every user and also block access to local folder and USB drive?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be really interested in hearing if you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: This sounds like a jailed environment to me...

Comment: does this helps you http://www.powerbrokeropen.org/

Comment: For clarification, are you asking (basically) how to auto-mount a network drive? (In Windows something like `net use.../persistent:yes`?)